# Preferred apt repository

Tags: apt, repository

If I have to two repositories listed in my sources.list or sources.list.d is there a way to tell apt which is preferred?

My exact use case is if a package is found on the intranet repository and on the remote repository I want apt to always use the intranet one.  Right now it seems to pick randomly between the two.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming your package repository is at `repo.company.net`, creating a file called e.g. `/etc/apt/preferences.d/company-pinning` containing the following will do the trick:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin repo.company.net
Pin-Priority: 600
```

The default priority is `500`, so this will prefer the latest version from the intranet server.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by modifying your /etc/apt/preferences file; it's commonly referred to as "APT pinning". Here are some guides with details:

- http://jaqque.sbih.org/kplug/apt-pinning.html
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto
- http://www.argon.org/~roderick/apt-pinning.html

Comment: I read the manpage for apt_preferences.  It has this line: "*The APT preferences file does not affect the choice of instance, only the choice of version.*"  It looks like APT preferences wont solve my specific use case.

Comment: I think apt-pinning is Debian-only due to the fact that Ubuntu doesn't differn between stable, testing, unstable... maybe for Multimedia or so... bit normally the versions should be never...

Answer (score 4):

It should be enough to list the intranet source first, in `sources.list`. According to the manual:

> It is important to list sources in order of preference, with the most preferred source listed first. Typically this will result in sorting by speed from fastest to slowest (CD-ROM followed by hosts on a local network, followed by distant Internet hosts, for example).

From a cursory look at the source, `sources.list` is traversed first, then the files in `sources.list.d` in an order that you can't control.

Comment: That's a bummer.  I wanted to distribute a package that dropped the intranet repo info in sources.list.d.  But it looks like I'll have to edit the sources.list in the post-install, yuck.